# Transaction Management

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm

In my code I am updating two table, one after the other.

update(table1_details);

update(table2_details);

So if the update fails in table1 , table2 should not be updated or should be rolled back.

How to handle this situation. I know I have to use transaction. Can some one help with code !!!
 I am using Java with spring and hibernate .

Comment: Where is the problem ? Can't you read online documentation ? For example : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html (first google answer on 'spring hibernate transaction' search) !

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit broad and there are several ways to implement this but I would:

- Use Spring to inject Hibernate `SessionFactory` into DAOs objects.
- Use Spring to inject DAOs in a service object and call them inside a business method.
- Use Spring declarative transaction management at the business method level (either with  Spring AOP or `@Transactional`).

Something like this:

```
@Transactional
public void doSomething() {
    dao1.foo();
    dao2.bar();
}
```

For more details on the configuration, check the [Chapter 9. Transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html) of the Spring documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I can't recall the correct api, but something like this:

```
    Transaction tx = em.getTransaction();

    tx.begin();
    try {
        update1(); update2();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        failed = true
    }
    finally {
        if( !failed ) tx.commit();
        else tx.rollbacl();
    }
```